# Binary search tree. Pointer as reference parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am working on Binary search tree function. Why do I have to add a &sign in front of the node pointer? I thought it is already a pointer and it already points to a location. I understand that if I add a node, then I need to make sure the parent node point to the new node or the parent's node will still point to NULL. But why don't I have to do that if I pass my node pointer as node*&?

```
bool bst::remove123(int data, node*& x)
{
if (x == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
else if (x->getData() < data)
{
    return remove123(data, x->right);
}
else if (x->getData() > data)
{
    return remove123(data, x->left);
}
else
{
    node* old = x;
    if (x->left == NULL)
    {
        x = x->right;
    }
    else if (x->right == NULL)
    {
        x = x->left;
    }
    else
    {
        replacement(old, x->left);
    }
    delete old;
    return true;
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `&` is not an address-of operator here, it is a reference declaration. You need to go back and reread the explanation of pointers and references in your C++ book. The reason that the parameter needs to be a reference is because, when the node is removed, the original pointer to the node being removed needs to be replaced, and the easiest way to do so, in this recursive context, is to use a reference. See your C++ book for more information about references.

Comment: You pass in the reference to a pointer type `T*&` when you need to modify the pointer of `T*` type. Reference to pointer type is just like a reference to any other type.

Answer (score 0):

`node*& x` is a reference to a `node*`. This means that when `bst::remove123` modifies `x` to point to a different address, the code that called `bst::remove123` sees the same change in the `node*` variable that it passed to the method. If you declared the `x` parameter as `node *x` instead, then `bst::remove123` would only be modifying a *copy* of the variable passed in that parameter, and those changes would be lost after the method returned. While the `&` is used to designate a reference, this is very different to the `&` operator (often used with pointers) which returns the address of the variable following it.

```
int n = 10;
int *pn = &n; // Create a pointer to int, set it to the address of n.
int& rn = n; // Create an int reference, set it to reference the same variable as n.

*pn = 5; // Set n to 5 via a dereferenced pn. A dereferencing operator *
         // is needed to indicate that we want to change the memory that
         // pn points to, not the address that the pointer contains.

rn = 20; // Set n to 20 via the reference rn. Unlike with pointers,
         // references do not use a dereferencing operator.
```